# How to create footer fixed to bottom even scrolling?

Tags: css, reactjs, footer

I built a web app and i want to add some footer to the bottom , but the problem is that the footer that i created shows only at the end of the page and if i scrolling down he is still at same position

for example:
I open a new tab of my app and i see this:
[image]

If i scroll down the page i see this:
[image]

display:"fixed" in my css is not good option to me because I want the footer be under all items,stick to buttom of the page.

Users will se the footer only if they scroll down until the end of the page.

this is my css style:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#17a2b8;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
```

my Footer:
import React from "react";
import './Footer.css'

```
const Footer = () => (
  <footer>
    <p>This is some content in sticky footer</p>
  </footer>
);
```

export default Footer;

*******EDIT*******

after i change my css style to :

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#17a2b8;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

.main-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
   }
```

and wrap my App with main-wrapper div:

```
 return(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
     <div className="main-wrapper">
    <Fragment>
        <Navbar/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Switch>
        <div className="container">
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles}/>
          <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={Profile}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/create-profile" component={CreateProfile}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/edit-profile" component={EditProfile}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/add-education" component={AddEducation}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/add-experience" component={AddExperince}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/posts" component={Posts}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/posts/post/:id" component={Post}/>
          </div>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </Fragment>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)}
```

I still have a little bit margin:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried that actually includes `display:"fixed"` and what exactly you don't like about it? (or without any special display at all, just a regular static footer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.main-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```
return(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
    <div className="main-wrapper">
        <Navbar/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing}/>
        <Switch>
        <div className="container">
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route exact path="/profiles" component={Profiles}/>
          <Route exact path="/profile/:id" component={Profile}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/create-profile" component={CreateProfile}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/edit-profile" component={EditProfile}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/add-education" component={AddEducation}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/add-experience" component={AddExperince}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/posts" component={Posts}/>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/posts/post/:id" component={Post}/>
          </div>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)}
```

This is will work now

Comment: almsost perfect, still have a little bit space between the bottom and footer.

Comment: check your footer or some other component has some margin. Rid of that it will work. And if you can share a screen shot i will understand what your mean by that

Comment: I just delete the "abosulte" and its fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the entire page in a div and apply the below styles for the div:

```
.main{
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```